# Удаление cookie из CookieManager

Tags: java, android, cookie, webview

Вообще такая ситуация, есть 2 WebView, в одном я хочу что бы куки сохранялись после выхода. В другом - нет (куки устанавливаю сам при запуске).  Вот так разрешаю куки для первого:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
```

Подскажите как со вторым сделать? пробовал удалять сессию (в DestroyView, это фрагмент), работает через раз. Если удалять все куки то работает отлично, пробовал устанавливать куки `null` и добавлять время дату для удаления, не помогает, если старые куки остаются - то вместе с новыми их не принимает (меняется имя ключа)